# How to perform a sum on a lot of entitities in Google Datastore?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am trying to understand if Google Datastore can fit my needs.

I have a lot of entities and I need to perform a sum on a certain property.
Basically, I would like to be able to do `select count(value1) from entity1 where [some filter]`, entity1 is an entity that keeps track of some sort of data in its field/property `value1`.

I know these kind of functions are not available in datastore since it's not a relational database, so the most immediate solution would be to perform a `select` and then calculate the sum on the result set in the application. So I would have something like (using nodejs, but i don't care about the language):

```
query = client.query(kind='Task')
query.add_filter('done', '=', False)
results = list(query.fetch())

total = 0
for(v in results)
  total += v.value
```

The problem is that I have thousands of records, so results may be like 300 000 records.

What's the best way to do this without getting a bottleneck?

Comment: First question, how often do you have to do this.  Secondly how frequently are task 'done' status updated ?  Both of these number can affect what approach you take. For instance incrementing counts as you go, or just batching.  If you have counted something once does it need to be counted again ?.

Comment: Read operations (that are the ones that request the sum of the data) happen often. The 'done' was just to make an example.

The count may need to be re-done on occasions.

Comment: If you are only doing this occasionally, what do you mean by a bottleneck?  Is your concern overall execution time to do the sum?  I would estimate that summing 300k records would take roughly 2-5 minutes.

Comment: Wait, I need the total value frequently, so I need to read it fast. At the same time, the data that composes the total sum may be occasionally subject to change, meaning that the sum changes. This means that if I use the approach of calculating it every single time i perform a read operation, there is no problem. But if I store a separated entity with the total sum I need to update the total counter too.

Yes, I am concerned about the overall execution time of the sum, because users may request the total count quite often

Answer (score 1):

You can store a total sum in a separate entity. No matter how frequently users request it, you can return it within milliseconds.

When an entity which is included in the total changes, you change the total entity. For example, if a property changes from 300 to 500, you increase the total by 200. This way your total is always accurate.

If updates are very frequent, you can implement these updates to the total as tasks (Task Queue API) in order to prevent race conditions. These tasks will be executed very quickly, so your users will get very "fresh" total every time they ask.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to make count on Google Datastore is the official solution: [Shard Count](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).